# How to handle events with arguments in Typescript

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, typescript

I am upgrading a project from Typescript 0.8.x to 0.9.5, and including the latest JQuery*.d.ts from DefinitelyTyped.

I have a bunch of events like:

```
$(document).on("pagehide", (event, ui) => { ... } );
```

Which now produce the error:

```
error TS2082: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target:
1>  
1>      Call signatures of types '(event: JQueryEventObject, ui: any) => void' and '(eventObject: JQueryEventObject, ...args: any[]) => any' are incompatible:
1>  
1>          Call signature expects 1 or fewer parameters.
```

I can rewrite this as:

```
$(document).on("pagehide", (event) => { var ui = arguments[0]; ... } );
```

But that doesn't feel right.  What is the correct way to do this?

I see that jquerymobile.d.ts defines an interface JQueryMobileEvent which has the signature I want, and a JQueryMobileEvents which has a pagehide entry ... but I don't see it used anywhere.

(edit: replaced pagecreate with pagehide since it does actually take two arguments)

Comment: `pagecreate` omits only one object `event`.

Comment: Good point, too much copy & pase! s/pagecreate/pagehide/g though and the same question still holds

Comment: try `$(document).on("event", "[data-role=page]", function (e, ui)`. Here, `ui` object has more data to use. I know nothing about typescript, sorry =)